# Python text file to xml conversion

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, txt

I have the following text file:

```
"POLYGON ((7529 4573, 7541 4573, 7565 4577, 7586 4580, 7607 4584, 7633 4586, 7649 4591, 7675 4594, 7708 4600, 7758 4612))"
```

I would like to convert it to the following format:

```
"<Vertices><V X="7529" Y="4573" /><V X="7541" Y="4573" /><V X="7565" Y="4577" /><V X="7586" Y="4580" /><V X="7607" Y="4584" /><V X="7708" Y="4586" /><V X="7649" Y="4591" /><V X="7675" Y="4594" /><V X="13278" Y="4600" /><V X="7758" Y="4612" />
```

What I tried so far?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring

top = Element('Vertices')
child = SubElement(top, 'V')

child.text = "POLYGON ((7529 4573, 7541 4573, 7565 4577, 7586 4580, 7607 4584, 7633 4586, 7649 4591, 7675 4594, 7708 4600, 7758 4612))"
print(tostring(top))
```

How can I add the x and y co-ordinates to the XML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the below a try

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

text = "POLYGON ((7529 4573, 7541 4573, 7565 4577, 7586 4580, 7607 4584, 7633 4586, 7649 4591, 7675 4594, 7708 4600, 7758 4612))"
top = ET.Element('Vertices')
pairs = text[10:-2].split(',')
for pair in pairs:
    x, y = pair.strip().split(' ')
    child = ET.SubElement(top, 'V')
    child.attrib = {'X': x, 'Y': y}
ET.dump(top)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vertices>
   <V X="7529" Y="4573" />
   <V X="7541" Y="4573" />
   <V X="7565" Y="4577" />
   <V X="7586" Y="4580" />
   <V X="7607" Y="4584" />
   <V X="7633" Y="4586" />
   <V X="7649" Y="4591" />
   <V X="7675" Y="4594" />
   <V X="7708" Y="4600" />
   <V X="7758" Y="4612" />
</Vertices>
```